# how to find which value related to which array(ex:array a, array b) after storing randomly into another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic

I have two different kinds of arrays, and i have picked some random values from two different arrays and stored in another array, how can i find which values are related to which array

example....

```
var firstDbArray=[1,2,7,9,3,4,0,6,5,10]
var secondDbArray=[1,2,9,7,0,4,8,11,15,30,10,12]

var uniquefromtwoarrays= [];

  for (var i = 0; i < this.firstDbArray.length; i++) {
    if (this.secondDbArray.indexOf(this.firstDbArray[i]) === -1) {
      uniquefromtwoarrays.push(this.firstDbArray[i]);
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < this.secondDbArray.length; i++) {
    if (this.firstDbArray.indexOf(this.secondDbArray[i]) === -1) {
      uniquefromtwoarrays.push(this.secondDbArray[i]);
    }
  }
```

output of uniquefromtwoarrays is----> [3,6,5,8,11,15,30,12]

my question is ----> how can i find which value from which array in this output.

Comment: in case a value is common in both of the array what will be desired output ? you want to show origin of value or the the existence of value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think This small Snippet  will help you ....

```
if ( secondDbArray.indexOf(uniquefromtwoarrays[i] === -1 ) 
 // uniquefromtwoarrays[i] related to the first array
else 
// uniquefromtwoarrays[i] related to the second array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( secondDbArray.indexOf(uniquefromtwoarrays[i] === -1 ) 
 // uniquefromtwoarrays[i] is related to the first array
else 
// uniquefromtwoarrays[i] is related to the second array
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```js
var firstDbArray=[1,2,7,9,3,4,0,6,5,10]
var secondDbArray=[1,2,9,7,0,4,8,11,15,30,10,12]

var uniquefromtwoarrays= [];

//create a new array were will be store the origin of the value
var uniqueArrayOrigin = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < this.firstDbArray.length; i++) {
    if (this.secondDbArray.indexOf(this.firstDbArray[i]) === -1) {
      //each time you push a new value to the array of unique values,
      //push to the new array of origins the value origins
      uniquefromtwoarrays.push(this.firstDbArray[i]);
      uniqueArrayOrigin.push(0);
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < this.secondDbArray.length; i++) {
    if (this.firstDbArray.indexOf(this.secondDbArray[i]) === -1) {
      uniquefromtwoarrays.push(this.secondDbArray[i]);
      uniqueArrayOrigin.push(1);
    }
  }
  
for(i = 0; i<uniquefromtwoarrays.length; i++) {
 //Then, you can print the origin value by access to the same position as the unique values array (for this case 0 is for the first array and 1 is for the second array
 console.log(`origin: ${uniqueArrayOrigin[i]}; value: 
 ${uniquefromtwoarrays[i]}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through `uniquefromtwoarrays` and than check existence of value in the arrays

```js
var firstDbArray=[1,2,7,9,3,4,0,6,5,10]
var secondDbArray=[1,2,9,7,0,4,8,11,15,30,10,12]

var uniquefromtwoarrays= [];

for (var i = 0; i < this.firstDbArray.length; i++) {
  if (this.secondDbArray.indexOf(this.firstDbArray[i]) === -1) {
    uniquefromtwoarrays.push(this.firstDbArray[i]);
  }
}
for (i = 0; i < this.secondDbArray.length; i++) {
  if (this.firstDbArray.indexOf(this.secondDbArray[i]) === -1) {
    uniquefromtwoarrays.push(this.secondDbArray[i]);
  }
}

let object = {firstDbArray,secondDbArray}
uniquefromtwoarrays.forEach(value=>{
  let includeIn = Object.entries(object).filter(([key,array])=>array.includes(value)).map(([key])=> key)
  console.log(`${value} is from in ${includeIn.join(', ')}`)
})
```

In case you just want to see the origin you need to keep an extra variable to keep track of origin something similar to [Ricardo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56166487/9624435)